# Build errors even though my solution meets requirements

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a `.NET core` project(Which I just upgraded from classic .NET)

- All the projects are configured to be `Any CPU` + `Debug`
- Even though that is the case, when tried to run a build on TeamCity, it did throw following error

`error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Release|x64" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU")`

I did check back on my Solution settings and it shows that every project inside is configured to be `Any CPU`. I am not sure if there is an issue on Team City or I need to fix something locally.

- I also tried to build it locally with `msbuild` and it failed horribly with error `project must be in MSBuild XML namespace` error
- I think `Core` is not compatible with msbuild
- Because when I build the same Core project with `dotnet CLI` it built fine

Probably is it the same reason why TeamCity is failing? May be its build agent is based on msbuild and it is failing to understand that it is not a .NET project but it is a .NET CORE project?

If so, I can change the build Agent to Ubantu but before doing anything on my team's build server I just wanted to make sure that my assumptions are correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build .NET core projects, you have to configure TeamCity to use the .NET Core CLI tools to build your project, not the MSBuild runner. If your agent is not on the same server as the TeamCity server, the agent also has to have the >NET Core CLI tools installed to build the project.